# How to add "aliases" to mongodb so I dont have to type out the full command

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I was reading [this](https://zellwk.com/blog/install-mongodb/) article about how to install mongodb on macos using homebrew which I did successfully, but at the end of the article it says that you can add "aliases" like this:

```
alias mongod='brew services run mongodb-community'
alias mongod-status='brew services list'
alias mongod-stop='brew services stop mongodb-community'
```

How do I add those "aliases"?

Comment: What you have there is exactly what needs to be run.  See [How to create bash aliases](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/)

Comment: thanks! exactly what I was looking for